# mi pregunta es acerca de este error:Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios()

Tags: php, html5

hola tengo el siguiente problema y no encuentro la respuestas, lo que estoy haciendo es comparar si el usuario y la clave ingresada en el login existen en la base de datos me de acceso si no me muestre un error,estoy usando xamp con la versión de php7, para este proyecto estoy bajo el patrón de MVC,el error en concreto se encuentra en el código php que anexe,: $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);

```html
<div id="back"></div>
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <img src="vistas/img/plantilla/logo-blanco-bloque.png" class="img-responsive" style="padding:30px 100px 0px 100px">
  </div>
  <div class="login-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Ingresar al sistema</p>

    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="ingUsuario" required>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="ingPassword" required>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Ingresar</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

este es el codigo php

```
<?php
class ControladorUsuarios{
    /*=============================================
    INGRESO DE USUARIO
    =============================================*/

    public function ctrIngresoUsuario(){

        if(isset($_POST["ingUsuario"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingPassword"])){

                $tabla = "usuarios";

                $item = "usuario";
                $valor = $_POST["ingUsuario"];

                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);

                if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["ingUsuario"] && $respuesta["password"] == $_POST["ingPassword"]){

                    $_SESSION["iniciarSesion"] = "ok";

                    echo '<script>

                        window.location = "inicio";

                    </script>';

                }else{

                    echo '<br><div class="alert alert-danger">Error al ingresar, vuelve a intentarlo</div>';
                }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

este es el codigo de la clase modelosusuario

```
class ModeloUsuarios
{

     static public function mldMostrarUsuarios($tabla,$item,$valor)
     {
        $stmt= Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
        $stmt->bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetch();
     }

}
```

este es el codigo para la conexion con la base de datos:

```
class Conexion
{

    public function conectar()
    {
        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=post","root","");
        $link->exec("set names utf8");
        return $link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Publicá el código de la clase `ModeloUsuarios`. La estás incluyendo en el archivo que publicaste?

Comment: listo ya lo agrege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que tu método se llama `mldMostrarUsuarios` (m minúscula) y lo estás llamado como `MdlMostrarUsuarios` (M mayúscula).

Por otro lado, por una cuestión de estándar [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), `static` se tiene que declarar después de la visibilidad del método:

```
pulblic static function mldMostrarUsuarios()
```

Comment: amigo gracias por tu respuestra y tenias razon con los errores pero al aplicar tu solucion me da este nuevo error sin corregir el anterior: Deprecated: Non-static method Conexion::conectar() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\modelos\usuario.modelo.php on line 10

Comment: listo amigo ya funciona tenia un error en la base datos gracias

Comment: Estás usando `Conexion::conectar()` que es una llamada estática, pero el método `conectar()` no lo tenés definido como tal. Aregale `static`.